# Sending Basic Form to Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am new to web development. In this code, I am trying to create a form where the form in the index.php sends out info to database. My list.php should display the list of users entered. However, my index.php does not send the data to the database. My database in the phpMyAdmin is absolutely empty. I dont know where my error could be. Please help.
//Config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'mysql51-031.wc2.dfw1.stabletransit.com';
$dbuser = '549359_sargis';
$dbpass = '*********';
$dbname = '549359_sargis';
$table  = 'Contacts';

$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

// index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <?php include("config.php"); ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "style.css">

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $phone     = $_POST['phonenumber'];

    //$date      = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (firstname, lastname, email, phone_number, timesstamp) VALUES ('$firstname' , '$lastname' , '$email' , '$phonenumber', NOW())";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$query)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

}

?>


</head>

<body>
        <a href="list.php">View List</a><hr/>

<form action="index.php" method = "POST">
    <div>
        First name: <input type ='text' id='firstname' name='firstname'/><br />
        Last name: <input type = 'text' id='lastname' name='lastname'/><br />
        Email: <input type = 'text' id='email' name='email'/><br />
        Phone Number: <input type = 'text' id='phone_number' name='phonenumber'/><br />
        <input type = 'submit' value='Add' />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the error say? Where `$table` is initialized? What data type  is `timestamp` in your table?

Comment: There is no error. The database is just empty.
$table is initialized in config.php. i included that

Comment: Did you do `mysql_connect()` in your code anywhere? Did you also do `mysql_select_db()`?

Comment: Show us `config.php`. Wipe out any sensitive information first (e.g. login info)

Comment: Yes, mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db is in config.php

Comment: I included config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Add `name='submit'` to your form button. because of `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. This condition always is `false` in your code so.

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add' />
                <!-- ^^^^ -->
```

**2)** Your form action is set to `action="list.php"` and form data will submit to this file.

Be sure that your database insert query is in right file: `list.php`. This means that you should move your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }` block to `list.php` or change form action to `action="index.php"` (current file) so.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
         <!-- ^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

**3)** Add these lines top of your code to turn on errors to detect what is happen.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**4)** Add `var_dump($_POST)` to check is your form data submit successfully or not. So output should be an array by form data. Otherwise you are in wrong way.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
```

**5)** Datetime formats in MySQL should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. 
Use MySQL method instead of `$date` to get the current timestamp `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " 
    (firstname, lastname, email, phone_number, timesstamp) 
VALUES 
    ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$phonenumber', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
```

Comment: I changed form action to action="index.php".
I fixed the TIMESTAMP. And I do not get any error messages.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` What do you get by this after form submit?

Comment: The code now works after I added the     var_dump($_POST);
Why is this function necessary?

Comment: @Sako what did you get? var_dump only outputs `$_POST` variable. It's not necessary so.

Comment: @Sako I got it why you have in wrong way. check number `1` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your variables in curly braces:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (firstname, lastname, email, 
                                    phone_number, timesstamp) VALUES 
           ('{$firstname}' , '{$lastname}' , '{$email}' , '{$phonenumber}',
           '{$date}')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you posted the content of `index.php` your problem seems to be that you submit your form to `list.php` but your data handling code is in `index.php`.

```
<form action="list.php" method = "POST">
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

No wonder that you don't have any error messages and no data in the table. It's because your code is not being executed.

Therefore either move your data handling code to `list.php` or make a self submitting form leaving value of `action` attribute blank

```
<form action="" method = "POST">
             ^^
```

and redirect to `list.php` after successful insertion of data.

Now if your `timestamp` is of type `datetime` or `timestamp` then either change

```
$date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

to

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

or change your query string to use MySql's build function [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which is a synonym for `NOW()`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (firstname, lastname, email, phone_number, timesstamp) 
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$phonenumber', NOW())";
```

**On a side note:** Instead of interpolating query strings use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. In its current state you code is wide open to SQL injection and you use deprecated `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: I tried changing list.php to index.php. Then I tried leaving it blank. Still I get no data in my database.

Comment: Thank for your help. Unfortunately, after changing form action to action = "index.php", my database is still empty